# How to create DropDown for Date filtered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In controller I had created a DropDown list for Date, now I need to filter dates and to take dates >= from Today.

here is code of DropDown list which I need to filter like this:

```
ViewBag.Datum = new SelectList(db.tbl_relacii, "DatumR", "DatumR").Where("DatumR" >= DateTime.Now.Date());
```

How to filter DropDown list?
Also in database table I put like Date format, but when I take data in DropDown list without .Where I see included Time like this **23.03.2017 00:00:00**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to filter the result before creating the dropdownlist items i.e. `SelecList` then you would need to filter them first and then pass the filtered list to `SelectList`'s constructor:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.Date; // as Ef wouldnl't be able to translate to sql 
                                 if we add it within Where directly
ViewBag.Datum = new SelectList(db.tbl_relacii
                                 .Where(x=>x.DatumR >= date),
                               "DatumR", 
                               "DatumR");
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution :).